# Add default language highlighting to [google-chrome-extension] and [google-chrome-app]

Tags: support, tags, syntax-highlighting

The tags [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) and [google-chrome-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-app) currently have syntax highlighting disabled.

This is a problem, since very often people ask questions without [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag (or with just one of those tags) and we have to edit the tags just to highlight code in question/answers. This unnecessarily bumps the question in the Active queue and is not beginner-friendly.

Note though that I'm not sure if it should be `lang-js`. There are CoffeeScript/Dart questions, there are questions about Native Hosts that can be in any language, there are HTML snippets, etc. Though the language tag is usually included in those cases where it's not JavaScript.

I think it's safer to make it `default`

Comment: You don't need to edit the tags to specify the highlighting, you can do it manually - this will still bump the question though.

Comment: @Joe I know - but if I specify a tag, this will also highlight all answers.

Comment: Yes, because many times there are no language tags on questions. I try to clean this up by editing if there is code, but it's frequent that it's missing.

Comment: @Deduplicator As far as I can tell, there is a difference between "none" (do not even try) and "default" (detect language). Correct me if I'm wrong.